# onclick triggering on page load

Tags: javascript, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have an icon in a menu that on click triggers a function to display a side panel, however it is also triggering it on page load.

This is the code:

```
<li class="btn-open-sidecart" onclick="openSideCart()"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-lg"></i></li>
```

This is the function that is triggered on click:

```
function openSideCart() {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "block";
}
```

How can I prevent the function triggering on page load?

Comment: Please click `[<>!` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with relevant frameworks and plugins (from cdn). It seems you may be using some "sidecart.js" which may have a "open when loading" setting as default

Comment: You were the one to tell me sidecart was part of that package

Comment: The code you have shown so far does not explain why the sidecart is open on load if you have css that makes it closed on load

Answer (score 1):

You can use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```
document.addEventListener('load', () => {
  openSideCart();
});
```

Instead of use inline event use always `addEventListener` for your button for example:

```js
document.querySelector('.btn-open-sidecart').addEventListener('click', () => {
  openSideCart();
})
/*
 *  document.querySelector('.btn-open-sidecart').addEventListener('click', openSideCart) short version
 */

function openSideCart(){
  console.log('trigger');
}
```

```html
<li class="btn-open-sidecart"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-lg"></i> icon</li>
```

Comment: Would this go outside the function? I have just tried this with no luck. Does ```load``` indicate on page load? as I want it to trigger ```onclick```

Comment: if you need just on click use second code i suggest

Comment: `document.querySelector('.btn-open-sidecart').addEventListener('click', openSideCart);` even

Comment: and
`document.addEventListener('load', openSideCart);`

Comment: @mplungjan right, i prefer always use function for the future implement.

Comment: Code edited above. I have tried adding ```document.querySelector``` to the js. I wrapped in a function, partly because I was getting an error and partly because I have no idea what I am doing. Now the icon doesnt respond on click but it is still triggered on page load.

Comment: There must be a script or CSS that opens it.

Comment: Have you add triggerme class? you can use any name

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Now I have done exactly as you have done above and in console I get this error ```side-cart.js?ver=5.8:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null```.

Comment: What is the point of `triggerme` when the class of the button is `btn-open-sidecart`  - which is more describing than triggerme

Comment: @mplungjan It was just to let the user know that he could use any class.

Comment: Most likely sidecart.js is a plugin that defaults to open cart

Comment: @ayecee that mean the querySelector fail. try to use directly your class like my example ( i change it).

Comment: Why you put `addEventListener` into `cartClick()` function ? and why instead of use doeblo function for open and close don't use `directly classList.toggle`

Comment: The code in the question is the old code. Before you edited. Now it is exactly as you have done above.

Comment: You have a live version?

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your help. I have managed to fix the issue. It was a very careless mistake with the css! Width was no 0! Still strange that ```addEventListener click``` would'nt work, but I have reverted to original inline method.